# Getting only the name of the session in screen?

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, gnu-screen

How to get only the session names in `screen -ls`?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe with parsing the outpout?

### For unnamed sessions:

```
$ screen -ls | grep -oP '\d+\.[\d\w-]+\.[\w\d]+'
4889.pts-0.myhostname
```

### For named sessions:

```
$ screen -ls | grep -oP '\d+\.\S+'
14819.namedsess
14678.with1.num
```

#### To gather the name only:

```
$ screen -ls | grep -oP '\d+\.\S+' | grep -oP '(?<=\d\.)\S+'
namedsess
with1.num
```